# Heroku issue with one database: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Tags: node.js, heroku

I can connect locally, and I can connect when I change just the DATABASE_URL to another database that is hosted on Heroku, but I can't get a specific azure-hosted database to work, it always results in a timeout error:

> Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within
> 60 seconds of launch

db.js

```
const dbnexus = new Sequelize(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
  dialect: 'postgres',
  logging: true,
  operatorsAliases: Sequelize.Op.Aliases,
  dialectOptions: {
    ssl: {
      require: true,
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
  },
});
```

app.js

```
dbnexus
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => dbnexus.sync())
  .then(() =>
    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, (res) => {
      console.log(`[server]: App is listening on ${process.env.PORT}`);
    })
  )
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log('[server]: Server Crashed');
    console.log(e);
  });
```

My Heroku environment:

```
DATABASE_URL = [matches local environment DATABASE_URL connection string]
PGSSLMODE = require
SSLMODE = require
```

All the other questions about this error were issues with how the port was being set, but I am doing it the way they all suggest, and it works with a different database, so I don't think that's actually the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Heroku doesn't use static IPs, so the server wasn't allowing it through. I don't know why this produced a time-out error instead of something more informative. I ended up using a proxy (QuotaGuard with qgtunnel is the only thing I could get to work with Sequelize and Postgres) and then whitelist the static IP's that created.